# Create the folder/file path based on the indent

Tags: java

I want to create the path of a particular file based on the indent. I have a command which returns me the structure of the project in the repository. like as shown below

```
Requirement
  abc.doc
Software
    Code
       File
         aaa.c
         bbb.c
```

I want to know if I can get the path of aaa.c as \Software\Code\File. It would be very helpful if you can give me some ideas how to do this.

Comment: you can, but AFAIK there is no library to do this.  You would need to write some code.

Comment: Well yes - you will have to build the path in code

Comment: Yes you can. You need to code though... Please post what you've tried to achieve your desired result, tehn we can tell how to improve that.

Comment: it would be great if you give some ideas how to do it..

Comment: A naive algorithm would be: 1.) if this line has more indent than the previous, it's a child of the previous 2.) if it has the same indent as the previous, it's a sibling of the previous (i.e. it's a child of the parent of the previous). 3.) if it has a lower indent, check for the first predecessor with the same indent as this: the current line is a sibling of that line.

Comment: @JoachimSauer. Thankyou for the algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep a map of <indent size, last file with that indent>. For each line processed, look up in the map the entry with (current line's indent - 1). That is the parent of your current file.

Do note that you'll need some convention to disambiguate files from folders. You could also assume that all leaf nodes (those without children) are files, but in that case there will be no way to represent an empty folder.

A solution that assumes all leaf nodes are files:

```
final Map<Integer, FileDesc> history = new HashMap<>();
final Set<File> files = new HashSet<>();
history.put(-1, new FileDesc(basePath, false));
for (String line : inputLines) {
  final int indent = indentSize(line);
  final String fileName = fileName(line);
  final FileDesc 
    parent = history.get(indent-1),
    previous = history.get(indent),
    current = new FileDesc(new File(parent.f, fileName), true);
  parent.isFile = false;
  if (previous != null && previous.isFile) files.add(previous.f);
  history.put(indent, current);
}
for (FileDesc desc : history.values())
  if (desc.isFile) files.add(desc.f);
```

---

```
class FileDesc {
  final File f;
  boolean isFile;
  FileDesc(File f, boolean isFile) { this.f = f; this.isFile = isFile; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marko. what is you mean by 'last file with that indent'?

Comment: The file that you created processing the last preceding line with that indent. Simply put, for each line that you process, put into the map <current line's indent, file that I created>.

Comment: There, hope that code sketch that I added helps to clear it up for you.

Comment: @Marko.. that was so great of u.. :)

Comment: Does it work for you? I didn't test it. Or compile it, for that matter :)

Comment: i m in the process of implementing it.. can i contact you further also for this matter??

Comment: That would be best done by posting a new question. Use SO as an answering cloud, don't depend on a single answerer :) If I'm online at that time, I'll be glad to help again.

Comment: the HashMap doesnt seem to work because the 'key' which is the indent is not unique

Comment: That's the point of it: it only keeps the last file with the indent. Why do you think it doesn't work? Maybe you didn't understand the purpose of the map in my solution: it is to determine the parent of each file as you read the input.

Comment: @Marko..sorry the internet connection was not there.  the problem is that the second leaf node overwrites the first leaf node every time. i need the path of all the leaf nodes.

Comment: My solution creates actual files and directories on the filesystem. If that is not what you intended for it, then just collect all `File` instances in a list. I edited the code.

Comment: Wonderful.. just a small typo:<pre>for (File f : files )
  if (!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();<code>

Comment: No, not a typo. This worked even before introducing the file list. Most of the files are created during the main loop. Notice that each time I am about to replace a map entry, I first create the file that will be evicted from the map. The bottom loop covers only those files that remain in the map after the main task is done.

Comment: i understand now. Basically, i wanted to get the path of all the files at the end. I dont have to create the directory structure. So, since in "files" contain all the files with the path name, i use a FileWriter to write all the file names with their path. Thankyou once again

Comment: If that is your use case, you'll have to redesign somewhat. The list will contain both files and directories as it stands now. I'll fix the code in a second to match your use case.

Comment: now there seems to be some problem.In the 'files', it adds the path multiple times

Comment: Change the file list to file set, then.

Comment: Exatly. That's how a `HashSet` works. A `LinkedHashSet` preserves insertion order, however.